# Merge 2 files and sort them

Tags: c++

I have 2 txt files where I have numbers > 0 and I have to combine and sort them. Also there cannot be 2 same values.

Here are values of files.
File1:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

File2:

```
1
3
6
8
10
```

The output should look like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
10
```

The code which I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fr1,*fr2;
    int fst, snd, p[256], i=0, n=0;
    bool f1=true,f2=true;

    fr1 = fopen("txt/cisla.txt","r");
    fr2 = fopen("txt/cisla2.txt","r");

    while(feof(fr1) == 0 && feof(fr2) == 0)
    {

        if (f1) fscanf(fr1, "%d", &fst);
        if (f2) fscanf(fr2, "%d", &snd);

        printf("%d - %d\n", fst, snd);

        if (fst == snd) 
        {
            f1 = true;
            f2 = true;
            p[i] = fst;
        }   else if (fst > snd)
        {
            p[i] = snd;
            f1 = false; 
            f2 = true;
        }   else
        {
            f2 = false;
            f1 = true;
            p[i] = fst;
        }

        i++;

    }

    fclose(fr1);
    fclose(fr2);

    printf("\n\n\n");

    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
            printf("%d\n", p[j]);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

The result of this is:

```
1 - 1
2 - 3
3 - 3
4 - 6
5 - 6
6 - 6
7 - 8


1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

The bottom part is the array. At top I am writing the values which are read. The thing is it seems to stop at the end of the first file but I want it to continue the second one even if the first one is at the end

Comment: Your files are sorted, right?

Comment: `system("cat file1 file2 > sort");` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The thing is it seems to stop at the end of the first file

That's because you told it to do so - the continuation condition that you have is that both `feof`s returned zero:

```
while(feof(fr1) == 0 && feof(fr2) == 0) {
    ...
}
```

> I want it to continue the second one even if the first one is at the end

Add two more loops after the first one, to write out the "tail" of the file with the larger elements:

```
while(feof(fr1) == 0 && feof(fr2) == 0) {
    ... // Do the merge
}
while(feof(fr1) == 0) {
    ... // Read from fr1, and write to the output
}
while(feof(fr2) == 0) {
    ... // Read from fr2, and write to the output
}
```

Comment: if I change it to OR it will crash and how can I comepare the variables then if I make 2 different loops?

Comment: @DeiForm These two "tail" loops come after the "merge loop". I edited the answer to illustrate.

Comment: well I still dont get it, the first will do the same as I get now, and then what should I do in the 2nd loops ?

Comment: @DeiForm Loop #1 does what you do already. Loop #2 reads from fr1, and writes to the output whatever remains there after loop #1. Loop #3 reads from fr2, and writes to the output whatever remains there after loop #1. Note than only one of the two added loops #2 and #3 will execute, so it will be loops #1+#2, loops #1+#3, or just the loop #1, but never all three.

Comment: @DeiForm Also note that the loops #2 and #3 may need to skip some entries. You would need to store the last value written to the output, and make sure that you wouldn't write it again. You would have to deal with it in your loop #1 as well.

Comment: It is working :) but one small problem. the 8 number is missing in the output

Comment: As you noticed. The last value can be retrieved like this ? if (feof(fr1)) p[i] = snd; for example?

Comment: @DeiForm The reason the 8 is missing is that it sits in the `snd` variable when loop #1 finishes. You should add something like this `if (!f1) p[i++]=fst; if (!f1) p[i++]=snd;` between the first and the second loops.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop says to continue while BOTH files are not at the end; I think you want it to continue as long as EITHER is not at the end.  Of course, you'd better be sure not to try and read from the one that IS at the end...

Comment: Could you be please more specific, from this I think I should change the while loop from AND to OR, but how can I not read from the file which is already at the end?

Comment: Inside the loop, you could check a file's eof before reading it.

Answer (score 0):

This small improvement could be of help.

```
while(feof(fr1) == 0 || feof(fr2) == 0)
{}
```

This is because you want to loop or read untill both the files are not completely read.

Btw, why can't you use some generic container..

Comment: this will make it to crash, the loop will never end

Comment: where did it crashed?

Comment: it kept writing then 7 - 8 all the time

Answer (score 0):

Your question is tagged as **C++**, but the code presented doesn't look like it. It looks more like **C**.

It's much easier to accomplish what you're trying to do if you avoid reinventing the wheel and use the *C++ standard library*.

Here's a simple example of how to do it using `std::vector` and the standard library:

```
// Open file streams for reading.
std::ifstream fr1{"file1.txt"};
std::ifstream fr2{"file2.txt"};

// Read number tokens into a std::vector from both files.
std::vector<int> v{std::istream_iterator<int>{fr1}, std::istream_iterator<int>{}};
v.insert(std::begin(v), std::istream_iterator<int>{fr2}, std::istream_iterator<int>{});

// Sort the vector.
std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v));

// Remove consecutive duplicates (move them to back of vector).
auto end = std::unique(std::begin(v), std::end(v));

// Remove duplicate elements.
if (end != std::end(v)) {
    v.erase(end, std::end(v));
}

// Output vector.
for (int i : v) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

[**Look at this live example**](http://ideone.com/86uge1)